# Convert negative seconds to hour:minute:second

Tags: java

I would like to create a constructor that takes in seconds and converts it to HH:MM:SS. I can do this pretty easily with positive seconds, but I'm running into some difficulty with negative seconds.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private final int HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, TOTAL_TIME_IN_SECONDS;

public MyTime(int timeInSeconds) {
   if (timeInSeconds < 0) {
        //Convert negative seconds to HH:MM:SS
    } else {
        this.HOUR = (timeInSeconds / 3600) % 24;
        this.MINUTE = (timeInSeconds % 3600) / 60;
        this.SECOND = timeInSeconds % 60;
        this.TOTAL_TIME_IN_SECONDS
                = (this.HOUR * 3600)
                + (this.MINUTE * 60)
                + (this.SECOND);
    }
}
```

If the timeInSeconds is -1 I want the time to return 23:59:59, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (time < 0)
    time += 24 * 60 * 60;
```

Add that to the start of the constructor.
While insted of IF if you expect big negative numbers.

Comment: the part about "while" is not very efficient. Modulo is much better:  -1%86400 = 86399

Comment: Just tried that... doesn't work. Knowing it's negative you must do this: 86400 + num%86400; to obtain 86399 from -1.

Comment: you are right - sorry. I got confused with how % works in Python (it would return 86399 in python). But still the general idea is correct - that % is more efficient than while.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyTime {
  private final int HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, TOTAL_TIME_IN_SECONDS;
  private static final int SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 86400;

  public MyTime(int timeInSeconds) {
     prepare(normalizeSeconds(timeInSeconds));
  }

  private int normalizeSeconds(int timeInSeconds) {
      //add timeInSeconds % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY modulo operation if you expect values exceeding SECONDS_IN_A_DAY:  
      //or throw an IllegalArgumentException
      if (timeInSeconds < 0) {
       return SECONDS_IN_A_DAY + timeInSeconds;
     } else {
       return timeInSeconds;
     }
  }

  private prepare(int timeInSeconds) {
        this.HOUR = (timeInSeconds / 3600) % 24;
        this.MINUTE = (timeInSeconds % 3600) / 60;
        this.SECOND = timeInSeconds % 60;
        this.TOTAL_TIME_IN_SECONDS
                = (this.HOUR * 3600)
                + (this.MINUTE * 60)
                + (this.SECOND);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if (timeInSeconds < 0) {
    return MyTime(24 * 60 * 60 + timeInSeconds);
}
```

Thus it would loop, and you would utilize your existing logic.

You can replace the `if` with a `while` loop in order to avoid recursion

Comment: similar comment to Sergio answer - while is not very efficient here. Modulo (%) is much better